# LaTeX fails to compile (using "rmarkdown::render()" with R)

Tags: r-markdown, render, ubuntu-22.04

I have an R script that I want to render, to get a pdf document mixing R code and its output.
So in RStudio's console I issue command:

```
> rmarkdown::render("Code/AnalyzeDataMFSQuant.R", "pdf_document")


processing file: AnalyzeDataMFSQuant.spin.Rmd
  |...............                                              |  25% [unnamed-chunk-1]                                                    
Continue the installation anyway? (Y/N) Y
tlmgr: setting option sys_bin to /home/bertrand/bin.
tlmgr: updating /home/bertrand/.TinyTeX/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
output file: AnalyzeDataMFSQuant.knit.md

/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS AnalyzeDataMFSQuant.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output AnalyzeDataMFSQuant.tex --lua-filter /home/bertrand/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /home/bertrand/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log AnalyzeDataMFSQuant.log.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `AnalyzeDataMFSQuant_files/figure-latex/Things (Gifts, art, cards, jewellery, family heirlooms)-1.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile AnalyzeDataMFSQuant.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See AnalyzeDataMFSQuant.log for more info.
```

The strange thing, is that render works with other R script, so I guess my installation of tinytex is fine

I copied several parts of the AnalyzeDataMFSQuant.R in another file, and issued render again. It works, as long as I do not include the following piece of code:

```
ggplot(MFS_RespondentLevelOfConfidenceInSouvenirReachingHeirs, aes(x = HowConfidentDescendantsWillFind, y = PctInterested)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "skyblue") +
  labs(title = "Percentage of people who believe in souvenir naturally reaching heirs ",
       x = "Level of confidence (1= No confidence, 5=full confidence)",
       y = "Pct of respondents") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found out that there were comments in the script, which contained a dash just after the hash (i.e. "#-"). I just had to delete the dashes for the script to work.
Now if some one can tell me why, I would actually be very much interested.
Is this a bug of "render"?